# Comment Python function calls in a string with source code

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to comment function calls from a Python source code.

I read the source code in a string, and then I'm trying to apply some regex to to comment method calls.

Here is an simple example working:

```
s = open(path, 'r').read()
# comment method calls
result = re.sub('(^[.\w]+\(.*\))', r'#\1', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

As you can see, I'm commenting functions in the first indentation level of the source(code outside `__name__ == '__main__'`, methods, and classes)

But, how can I make this regex work with multiple line calls?

Example, if I have the following code into string:

```
Builder.load_string('''
    type: 'example'
    callback: my_callback()
''')
```

How can I comment each line of this call?

Comment: I don't think it is a propper job for Regexps. Maybe you should try to use a more specific parser: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/parser.html

Comment: It might be helpful to take a look at the [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module

Comment: Why would you *want* to comment each line? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it's for an IDE, and this IDE must to load/import user classes. So I'm trying to comment these methods, and then import it.

Comment: e.g, if I have a class `MainApp`, the user may add in the last line: `MainApp().run()` I'm trying to avoid this kind of calls. I need to load the MainClass, but avoid any kind of call

Comment: You mean you want to comment *out* any calls at the top level? That seems very fragile.

Comment: Yes. It's a UI designer, so it's important to load classes to get information about UI properties defined in each class properties. So, to the UI, these calls can be ignored.

Comment: Do you just want to do this at runtime?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes. I have a GUI app running, the user enters a source code, and I want to import the user classes at runtime to get more information about each class.

Comment: So you don't care about any logic i.e instances being created, you just want to import the classes without anything running?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham exactly, just classes

Comment: What info are you trying to get?

Comment: I'm rewriting this [file](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer/blob/master/designer/project_loader.py#L988) I need to import a class and be able to create a new instance from it.

Comment: would finding all the line numbers where there were calls  work? You could remove nodes with ast.NodeTranformer but it is not a trivial task because remove Call's can break other parts of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the line numbers you need to comment:

```
mod = "test1"
mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))


for n in p.body:
    if isinstance(n, ast.Expr):
        for node in ast.walk(n):
            if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
                print(node.lineno)
```

For a file like:

```
import math

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 4
    def bar(self):
        print("hello world")

    def foo(self):
        return self.bar()

def bar():
    return 123

f = Foo()    
f.bar()    
bar()
```

It will output `16`  and `18`  the two calls.

It is just a matter of ignoring those lines and writing the new source or doing whatever you want with the updates content:

```
import inspect
import importlib
import ast

def get_call_lines(mod):
    mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
    p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))
    for n in p.body:
        if isinstance(n, ast.Expr):
            for node in ast.walk(n):
                if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
                    yield(node.lineno)


from StringIO import StringIO
new = StringIO()
with open("test1.py") as f:
    st = set(get_call_lines("test1"))
    for ind, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if ind not in st:
            new.write(line)

new.seek(0)
print(new.read())
```

new will contain:

```
import math
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 4
    def bar(self):
        print("hello world")

    def foo(self):
        return self.bar()

def bar():
    return 123

f = Foo()
```

You could change the code at runtime with `ast.NodeTransformer` but it is not such a trivial task to remove nodes, the simplest approach for what you want would be to simply ignore the Call lines in the body

Comment: No prob, you're welcome , like I said in the answer there are other ways but they  are a lot more complex, for what you need this should be the most straightforward approach.